# Customizing a drupal webform for Drupal 6

Tags: webforms

I am working on a system that would require users to register online by filling out a membership application form. There used to be a PDF form that used to be filled out and sent for processing. The client wants the online form to be as close in appearance to this PDF form. Is it possible to customize a form created using webforms such that it can have some of these elements such as logos, images, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize form's HTML markup using Drupal's form alter hooks:

1. [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6)
2. [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#suffix)

after changing form's markup you should only styling form using CSS.